# Is it okay to not await async method call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have an application which will upload files. I don't want my application to halt during the file upload, so I want to do the task asynchronously. I have something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //less than 5 seconds
        PrepareUpload();
    }

    private static async Task PrepareUpload()
    {
        //processing

        await Upload();

        //processing
    }

    private static Task Upload()
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000));

        return task;
    }
}
```

The exceptions are being treated internally, so that is not a problem.

Is it okay to use async/away like a shoot and forget like this?

Comment: Yes. If you don't need to wait, don't wait.

Comment: Isn't it a bad practice?

Comment: This is too basic to be considered a practice. It is an operation that you may or may not use, depending on your need in the specific context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a console app, you *need* to wait. Otherwise, your application will exit, terminating all background threads and asynchronous operations that are in progress.

Comment: This is just an example of logic, the actual code is a Forms Application and doesn't finish after the upload.

Comment: In that case it's OK to do a fire-and-forget, if you're *sure* you want to. IMO, it's just as easy to `await` it.

Comment: But awaiting it would hang the application until the upload is done, no?

Comment: No. An `await` is an "*asynchronous* wait". The method will wait for it, but the UI thread will not.